# Write to multiple ES sink from Spark Streaming Job

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch

I'm using Spark streaming to process high volume data from Kafka queue and I need to write the result to two ES clusters set up.

I'm using "org.elasticsearch.elasticsearch-spark-XX" in my project and able to write to one ES cluster by using method `EsSpark.saveJsonToEs()` which internally fetches ES specific properties from immutable spark context.

So, if the spark context is immutable, how I can change the properties at run time and write results to multiple ES clusters.

Please suggest.

Ref - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/6.7/spark.html

Comment: can you try with `spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts` true and use each sparkcontext with one es sink ?

Comment: the below solution have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the below way with `spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts` should work...
create spark context session separately with new spark configuration .

```
conf.set("es.index.auto.create", "true")
conf.set("es.nodes", "XXXXXXXX")
conf.set("es.port", "9020")
conf.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
val sc1 = new SparkContext(conf)
```

---

```
conf.set("es.index.auto.create", "true")
conf.set("es.nodes", "yyyyyy")
conf.set("es.port", "9020")
conf.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
val sc2 = new SparkContext(conf)
```